# Error when calling glGetTexImage (atioglxx.dll)

Tags: opengl

I'm experiencing a difficult problem on certain ATI cards (Radeon X1650, X1550 + and others).

The message is: "Access violation at address 6959DD46 in module 'atioglxx.dll'. Read of address 00000000"

It happens on this line:

```
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,P);
```

Note:

- Latest graphics drivers are installed.
- It works perfectly on other cards.

Here is what I've tried so far (with assertions in the code):

- That the pointer P is valid and allocated enough memory to hold the image
- Texturing is enabled: glIsEnabled(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
- Test that the currently bound texture is the one I expect: glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_2D_BINDING)
- Test that the currently bound texture has the dimensions I expect: glGetTexLevelParameteriv( GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH / HEIGHT )
- Test that no errors have been reported: glGetError

It passes all those test and then still fails with the message.

I feel I've tried everything and have no more ideas. I really hope some GL-guru here can help!

EDIT:

After concluded it is probably a driver bug I posted about it here too: http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=295137#Post295137

I also tried GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT and it didn't help.

By some more investigation I found that it only happened on textures that I have previously filled with pixels using a call to glCopyTexSubImage2D. So I could produce a workaround by replacing the glCopyTexSubImage2d call with calls to glReadPixels and then glTexImage2D instead.

Here is my updated code:

```
{
  glCopyTexSubImage2D cannot be used here because the combination of calling
  glCopyTexSubImage2D and then later glGetTexImage on the same texture causes
  a crash in atioglxx.dll on ATI Radeon X1650 and X1550.
  Instead we copy to the main memory first and then update.
}
//    glCopyTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, PixelWidth, PixelHeight);  //**
GetMem(P, PixelWidth * PixelHeight * 4);
glReadPixels(0, 0, PixelWidth, PixelHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, P);
SetMemory(P,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);
```

Comment: Sounds like a driver bug. ATI's OpenGL drivers have a bad reputation in terms of stability. Features not used by a lot of programs may break. Retrieving a texture image is such a seldomly used feature. Sice you already ruled out all possible causes for failure, I suggest you report this as a bug to AMD/ATI.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll post on opengl.org drivers forum then. Seems like a couple of AMD engineers are active there.

Comment: +1 for trying all of the right things, and listing them in your question.  I agree that it sounds like a driver bug.  Be sure to update this question if you hear anything from a ATI developer :)

Comment: I've found a workaround, see my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You might take care of the GL_PACK_ALIGNEMENT. This parameter told you the closest byte count to pack the texture. Ie, if you have a image of 645 pixels:

- With GL_PACK_ALIGNEMENT to 4 (default value), you'll have 648 pixels.
- With GL_PACK_ALIGNEMENT to 1, you'll have 645 pixels.

So ensure that the pack value is ok by doing:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
```

Before your glGetTexImage(), or align your memory texture on the GL_PACK_ALIGNEMENT.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a driver bug. Having written 3D apis myself it is even easy to see how. You are doing something that is really weird and rare to be covered by test: Convert float data to 8 bit during upload. Nobody is going to optimize that path. You should reconsider what you are doing in the first place. The generic conversion cpu conversion function probably kicks in there and somebody messed up a table that drives allocation of temp buffers for that. You should really reconsider using an external float format with an internal 8 bit format. Conversions like that in the GL api usually point to programming errors. If you data is float and you want to keep it as such you should use a float texture and not RGBA. If you want 8 bit why is your input float?

Comment: I can agree with you in general but since glGetTexImage takes a type parameter it should be easy to cover with unit tests of that function. I did also test to keep the format constant (GL_FLOAT all the way) but the error remained. It was the specific combination of glCopyTexSubImage2D followed by glGetTexImage that caused the error.

Comment: I actually misread the original post and did not see the Get in glGetTexImage. That function is pretty much considered debug only. You are right about unit tests in principle but the gl api is so large it is not really feasible. 20 internal formats, 20 external, 20 states. Upload, copy, download, map. It's just to many combinations. And both copy and get are fringe features.